# Can a squarefree polynomial in K[x,y] not be squarefree in K[[x]][y]?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, factorization, weierstrass-preparation

In a UFD, as usual one says that $f$ is square-free if it is not divisible by the square of any irreducible element, i.e., if it has no multiple factor.

An polynomial $f\in k[x,y]$ can have more factors in the factorization over $k[[x]][y]$ than over $k[x,y]$.

> Is it possible for $f\in k[x,y]$ to be square-free in $k[x,y]$ but not in $k[[x]][y]$?

It looks like an easy question but I cant find a simple argument/example.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it seems to me that $(1+x)y^2$ is a square in $k[[x]][y]$ but not in $k[x, \, y]$, right?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi that's not squarefree.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: right, I missed the *squarefree* assumption.

Comment: How about $1+x$?

Comment: well, this is invertible in $k[[x]][y]$, so maybe does not count as "having multiple factors"

Comment: Yes, but in both cases there are no multiple factors

Comment: Actually, I don't know what "have multiple factors" is?

Comment: Is $\sqrt{1+x}$ defined as formal power series in characteristic $2$? If so, we  could take $(1+x)y^2+1$

Comment: In char 2 the only square root of $1+x$ is $1+x^{1/2}$

Comment: What is your understanding of "having multiple factors"? Is is just the same as "not square-free"?

Comment: @YCor: the ring $k[[x]]$ is a UFD, so the same is true for the polynomial ring $k[[x]][y]$. This means that every element in $k[[x]][y]$ factors uniquely (up to units) as the product of irreducible elements. A multiple factor is a (non-invertible) factor appearing with multiplicity at least $2$ in the factorization.

Comment: No.  The map ${\rm{Spec}}(k[\![x]\!])\to {\rm{Spec}}(k[x])$ is a regular morphism of noetherian schemes (i.e., flat with all fibers "geometrically regular": regular and remaining so after any finite extension of the base field of the fiber), as for the completion of any excellent ring at a prime (easy in the present case), so the same holds for ${\rm{Spec}}(k[\![x]\!][y]/(f))\to {\rm{Spec}}(k[x,y]/(f))$ for $f\in k[x,y]-\{0\}$ by base change. Thus, if $k[x,y]/(f)$ is reduced then so is $k[\![x]\!][y]/(f)$, so $f$ is squarefree in the UFD $k[\![x]\!][y]$ (i.e., no repeated irreducible factors).

Comment: In the preceding comment, for the (finite type!) base change step I am tacitly using EGA IV$_2$ 6.7.8(iv) to ensure that a geometrically regular noetherian algebra over a field $k$ remains regular (even geometrically so) after any scalar extension to a field finitely generated over $k$. This use of excellence is similar to that by which one proves that the analytification of a reduced scheme locally of finite type over $\mathbf{C}$ is reduced (as a complex-analytic space).

Comment: I was writing out a long and annoying argument using Gauß's lemma. The idea is that a polynomial over a *field* is squarefree if and only if its discriminant is nonzero, which can be checked before or after field extension. Unfortunately, this is only true in characteristic $0$; e.g. consider the irreducible polynomial $x^2-t$ over $\bar{\mathbb F}_2[t]$, which becomes a square over $\bar{\mathbb F}_2[\sqrt{t}]$. But @nfdc23's argument is much nicer than mine, and works in all characteristics.

Comment: @nfdc23: your nice comment deserves to be an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, since the case of constants is trivial (since non-square-free elements of $k[[x]]$ are multiples of $x^2$), there is a reduction to $k(x)[y]\subset k((x))[y]$.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, the essential content in this case is that $k(\!(x)\!)$ is a separable extension of $k(x)$ in the sense of field theory (hence a direct limit of smooth $k(x)$-algebras), which ultimately follows from the fact that for any finite extension $K/k(x)$ the tensor product $k(\!(x)\!) \otimes_{k(x)} K$ is reduced, as it is the product of the completions of $K$ at the finitely many places extending the $x$-adic one.  Please feel free to write an answer based on this, thereby avoiding the machinery of excellence (which I prefer since it gives geometric context to what is "really" going on).

Comment: And in $k[y][[x]]$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე:  Since $k[y][\![x]\!]/(f)$ is the completion of the excellent ring $k[x,y]/(f)$ with respect to the ideal $(x)$, one can conclude via the general fact that if $A$ is an excellent ring with completion $\widehat{A}$ for a chosen ideal then ${\rm{Spec}}(\widehat{A})\to {\rm{Spec}}(A)$ is a regular morphism and hence if $A$ is reduced then so is $\widehat{A}$: see [EGA IV$_2$, 7.8.3(v)].

Comment: @nfdc23: thank you very much for your answer (and all others for your comments)! Im not very experieced here, can I convert that comment into answer and accept it?

Comment: @Santiago I don't think there is any way to do that. In general if someone answers a question in the comments and for whatever reason doesn't want to make it an answer, you can answer the question yourself, quoting the comment or expanding on it, and of course crediting it, and accept it. You can optionally make the answer community wiki. In this case you could also just accept Lucifer's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of an argument in case that $k$ is a perfect field. Since a complete answer has already been given in the comments, a complete answer here is superfluous.

First you prove the polynomial $f$ is square free if and only if the ideal $I = (f_x, f_y)$ has finite colength in $k[x, y]$. You can define the colength simply as the dimension of $k[x, y]/I$ as a $k$-vector space. Also $f_x$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and similarly for $f_y$. To see the statement is true, observe that the curve $C = V(f)$ in affine $2$-space is reduced if and only if it has finitely many singular points. Here we use that that ground field is perfect, so nonsingular points of $C$ are smooth points of $C$.

OK, but now if $f = g^2h$ in $A = k[[x]][y]$ where $g$ is not a unit, then we see that the ideal $IA$ does not have finite colength in $A$ because $IA$ is contained in $(g)$ since $f_x = 2gg_xh + g^2 h_x$ and $f_y = 2gg_yh + g^2h_y$ and $A/(g)$ has infinite dimension as a $k$-vector space. We leave this to the reader as an exercise.

To conclude we need one final fact: if $I$ has finite colength in $k[x, y]$, then $IA$ has finite colength in $A$.

Two suggestions for proving the final fact come to mind: (1) you can prove this by classifying ideals having finite colength (do primary decomposition) and prove it for powers of maximal ideals by direct computation, or (2) you can use that the the image of $k[x, y] \to A/IA$ is dense in the $(x)$-adic topology, and hence if $IA$ has infinite colength, then $I$ must also have infinite colength. Cheers!